# How to get position and set listener of ImageButton in custom ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onclicklistener, imagebutton

i have a CustomListView which is loaded with AsyncTask.
I have a imageButton to the end of each row.

My probleme : When i click to my imageButton , nothing work.
I tried many solution like this :

[Android : how to set listener and get position of imagebutton click in a custom adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776755/android-how-to-set-listener-and-get-position-of-imagebutton-click-in-a-custom)

My ListView class who call AsyncTask :

```
public class listview extends Activity {

private ListView maListViewPerso;   
ImageButton imgButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#000000")));

    maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewperso);

    asyncTask asynchrone_task_tournee = new asyncTask(listview.this, maListViewPerso);
    asynchrone_task_tournee.execute();  

}
```

This is my imageButton where i want to get position and set a listener..
[image]

**EDIT 1** (answer comment) this is my `onPostExecute()` and there is my SimpleAdapter :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jArray) {        
    super.onPostExecute(jArray);

    JSONObject json_data=null;     
    HashMap<String, String> map;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    this.pDialog.dismiss();     



      Log.i("JSON_TOURNER",jArray.toString());

      for(int i=0;i < jArray.length();i++)
      {             
            try {

                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                 map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 map.put("titre", json_data.getString("time"));
                 map.put("description", json_data.getString("date"));
                 map.put("begin_hour", json_data.getString("hour"));
                 map.put("end_hour", json_data.getString("hour"));


                 listItem.add(map);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }     
      }

      SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (Mycontext, listItem, R.layout.list_type_tournee,
             new String[] {"titre", "description","begin_hour","end_hour"}, new int[] {R.id.miscellaneous, R.id.infos,R.id.begin_hour,R.id.end_hour});

      listview.setAdapter(mSchedule);


}
```

Comment: where is your `ListAdapter` code? you can implement it inside the `getView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

All right, if you use  controls like `ImageButton`, `CheckBox` ,`Button` etc in a `ListView` then you would face problems discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274231/listfragment-onlistitemclick-not-being-called) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list).

To solve this you need to add `android:focusable="false"` in the xml of your `ImageButton`.

If the above doesn't work then you should add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the **parent** layout of your `ImageButton` and then implement `onClickListener()` for the `ImageButton`.

for more see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421821/how-to-sense-what-has-been-clicked-within-an-android-list-view-element/21430972#21430972).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried to implement onClickListener() for the ImageButton, and pet android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to the parent layout. But when i run the apps, it's crash directly

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my probleme .
Finaly, i removed the imageButton, and i pet a frame layout in my linear layout, and i pet a listener on my listeView to open the dialog.

I pet android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" too, in my linear parent of the frame layout